# load content when click on menu

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts

Im using struts 1.3 + spring 2.5 + hibernate 3.

I have 2 table Category and Product.

```
---------CATEGORY--------- 
- cat_id(varchar)
- cat_name(varchar)
---------PRODUCT---------
- pro_id(int)
- cat_id(varchar)
- pro_name(varchar)
```

I load name of category from database as menu at top site using tags-logic

```
<logic:iterate id="cat" name="catList">
<bean:define id="ID" name="cat" property="catId" />
    <a href="/ListProduct.do?catId=<%=ID %>">
        <bean:write name="cat" property="catName" />
    </a> |
</logic:iterate>
```

Its will be display like this:

```
CAT1 | CAT2 | CAT3 | CAT4 |
```

I want when I click on CAT1 or CAT2..., its will be show product name of that category at below the menu. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you click menu link it will submit to action class and get the product details and forward to same page with product list. Use same iterator and bean:write tag to display in the same page.

Does it answer your question ?

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: I want this page will load data from both tables at the first time I visit. Can you give me any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

`<a onclick="showProducts('<c:out value="${ID}"/>')">`
and then implement javascript function to display popup windows with all products in this category. You can use some JQuery plugins for that.